# Delete or remove page

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a page with the following command in google Apps (script):

> page.createFileCabinetPage (newpagename, newpagename, "MAIN FOLDER NEW
>   PROJECT"). SetParent (page);

Is there any way to know how could create a button to delete it?
ex:
Button delete page.create?

Note: I have already created the button, just do not know how to delete the event page.
tks.

Comment: Where do you want to show the button ? In any case, you can see the UIService documentation to create a UI ( https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp )

Answer (score 0):

There is a [deletePage method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/page#deletePage%28%29).

```
  var newPage = page.createFileCabinetPage (newpagename, newpagename, "MAIN FOLDER NEW PROJECT");

  //your button would run
  newPage.deletePage();
```